# "Undefined Constant/Variable" Error in Laravel......Unable to show variable in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel, I have a variable in my dashboard controller (which extends the base controller) defined as follows:

**Dashboard Controller:**

```
public function dashboardData(){
    $toReturn = array();
    $toReturn['siteTitle'] = $this->data['panelInit']->settingsArray['siteTitle'];


    //------other things-----------//


    $toReturn['stats'] = array();

    //------some other things-----------//


    $toReturn['stats']['recieved'] = messagesList::where('userId',$this->data['users']->id)->where('messageStatus',1)->count();
```

This variable is shown in my main(index/default/home/whatever you call it) html template by using the {{}} syntax as follows:

**HTML Template**

```
   <div class="counter">   
   <div class="informational">{{dashboardData.stats.recieved}}</div>
   </div>
```

and it completely shows the result I expect....
but I want to show this same data in a layout blade that I am using... I am using the same html structure in the layout.blade (directory:/app/views) with {{dashboardData.stats.recieved}} but I am getting "**Undefined Constant**" and "**undefined Variable**" errors...

following is a glimpse of my routes.php:-

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'/','before'=>'auth.Ui|auth.token|api.csrf'),function(){
Route::get('/','DashboardController@index');

Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@dashboardData');
Route::get('/dashboard/baseUser','DashboardController@baseUser');

//-------------some things-------------//

Route::post('/dashaboard','DashboardController@dashaboardData');
```

I am quite new on laravel, I have stumbled upon the "view::share" and "view:make" thing but didn't quite get it how to do it perfectly & securely without a single error...
I also have a library setup in the "/app/libraries/initiation.php" that reflects some data to layout.blade....How do I show the data {{dashboardData.stats.recieved}} in the layout.blade without the errors "**Undefined Constant**" and "**undefined Variable**"...??? and also what would be the most correct, practical and most importantly secure way of doing so...???

Comment: Are you using angular or another JS framework? The syntax for `{{dashboardData.stats.recieved}}` is wrong for blade and should not 'completely shows the result I expect'.

Answer (score 4):

You access variables in incorrect way in your **Blade** template.

Replace

```
{{dashboardData.stats.recieved}}
```

with

```
{{$dashboardData['stats']['recieved']}}
```

Make sure that you pass the variable to the view from your controller:

```
public function dashboardData() {
  // your logic that generates $toReturn array

  return view('your_view')->with('dashboardData', $toReturn);
}
```

Comment: What I _really_ don't get is why "it completely shows the result I expect" in OP's non-blade code... maybe it's another templating engine.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo  It returns "Undefined variable: dashboardData"

Comment: Have you passed that variable to your blade template?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I am not sure whether to use "view::make" or "view::share" or "@include" for it so that it works correctly........

Comment: Do you want to access that variable with PHP or JavaScript? It's a huge difference

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I've already tried it.....Same error again....refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761541/undefined-constant-variable-error-using-laravel-with-angular-js-unable-to-show

Comment: You're code in that question still uses the invalid syntax in Blade template

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo tried with both {{dashboardData.stats.recieved}} and {{$dashboardData['stats']['recieved']}} and passed the variable too still can't get it....