# “Undefined Constant/Variable” Error using Laravel with Angular JS…Unable to show variable in blade

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am building a common backend office messaging app using laravel and angular js, I have a variable(named recieved) (which shows the total number of unread new messages) in my dashboard controller (which extends the base controller) defined as follows:

**Dashboard Controller:**

```
var $data = array();

public function dashboardData(){
$toReturn = array();
$toReturn['siteTitle'] = $this->data['panelInit']->settingsArray['siteTitle'];


//------other things-----------//


$toReturn['stats'] = array();

//------some other things-----------//


$toReturn['stats']['recieved'] = messagesList::where('userId',$this->data['users']->id)->where('messageStatus',1)->count();

}
return json_encode($toReturn);

}
```

I am using angular to for data/variable transfer/passing...following is my angular code snapshots:-

**Routes.js**

```
skyla.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/', {
  templateUrl : 'templates/main.html',
  controller  : 'dashboardController'
})
```

**app.js**

```
skyla.controller('mainController',function(dataFactory,$rootScope,$route,$scope) {
  var data = $rootScope.dashboardData;
  $scope.phrase = $rootScope.phrase;

  $scope.dashboardData = data;
  $rootScope.phrase = data.language;
  $scope.phrase = data.language;


}
```

The variable (recieved) is shown in my main(index/default/home/whatever you call it) html template of Laravel by using the angular {{}} syntax as follows:

**HTML(for Main.html Template)**

```
  <-------------some things-------------------------->

  <div class="counter">
  <div class="informational">{{dashboardData.stats.recieved}}</div>
  </div>

  <-------------some other things-------------------------->
```

and it successfully shows the output....

but I want to show this same data in a layout.blade.php that I am using for basic layout purposes so that the number of received new messages always appear in the navbar header for each user...

I am using the same html structure in the layout.blade.php (directory:/app/views) with angular {{dashboardData.stats.recieved}} syntax as:

**HTML(for Layout Blade)**

```
  <body ng-app="skyla" ng-controller="mainController">

  <-------------some things-------------------------->

  <div class="nav">
  <div class="informational">{{dashboardData.stats.recieved}}</div>
  </div>

  <-------------some other things-------------------------->

  </body>
```

but I am getting "Undefined Constant:dashboardData" and "undefined Variable" errors...

following is a glimpse of my Laravel routes.php:-

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'/','before'=>'auth.Ui|auth.token|api.csrf'),function(){
    Route::get('/','DashboardController@index');

    Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@dashboardData');
    Route::get('/dashboard/baseUser','DashboardController@baseUser');

    //-------------some things-------------//

Route::post('/dashaboard','DashboardController@dashaboardData');
```

I am quite new on laravel altogether with angular, I am not sure whether to pass the variable value to layout balde with php or angular and which would be the secure and a feasible practise...

I have stumbled upon the "view::share" and "view:make" (I have tried:return view('layout', ['dashboardData' => $toReturn]);) thing but didn't quite get it how to do it perfectly & securely without a single error...

I also have a library setup in the "/app/libraries/initiation.php" that reflects some data to layout.blade.php...

**My Question**

What would I do in the most easiest yet correct practise so that I can use angular {{dashboardData.stats.recieved}} syntax in the layout.blade.php without the errors "Undefined Constant" and "undefined Variable"...???
Please explain, tell me if you need more info...I'm picking up this work inbetween where a former dev has left the work uncompleted...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Undefined Constant/Variable" Error in Laravel......Unable to show variable in blade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749861/undefined-constant-variable-error-in-laravel-unable-to-show-variable-in-b)

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo The solution doesn't work and throws the same error as mentioned in the question....as "(I have tried:return view('layout', ['dashboardData' => $toReturn]);)"

Comment: did you manage to solve your problem? How did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a conflict between blade and angular since {{ }} parentheses are used in both. Also angular has its own way of rendering views.
The layout.blade.php interprets {{}} as its own instead of angulars. And in "pure" html you don't have that problem because it is rendered by angular on users side.

The easyest way to do what you're asking for (in my opinion) is to keep Laravel and Angular files separated and use Laravel as an API for angular app. So if you're planing on developing this for some time I would transform blade files into html files for preventing future headaches. :)

That said a way of hacking this situation is to echo this line with blade as a string or to swap curly braces with &#123 (html code for curly brace). 
So basically:

```
<div class="informational">&#123;&#123 dashboardData.stats.recieved  &#123;&#123 </div>
```